# How to show pointwise convergence (basic real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

the function $f_n : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by :

$f_n(x) = n(x^{1/n}-1)$

How do I show that $\{f_n \}$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = ln (x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\log x.$ Then $x=e^y$ and $$n(x^{1/n}-1)=n(e^{y/n}-1)=y\cdot\frac {e^{y/n}-e^0}{y/n-0}.$$ As $n\to \infty$ this converges to $y\cdot\frac {de^z}{dz}|_{z=0}=y=\log x.$

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $x\in (0,\infty)$, we have $$\lim f_n(x)=\lim \frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ so applying LHopitals rule we have $$\lim f_n(x)=\lim \ln(x)x^{\frac{1}{n}}=\ln(x)$$